# Relative referencing copy & paste issue

Tags: excel, vba

@dan, @minh & @erik, thank you so much for your time and help. Truly appreciate it. However I will have to rephrase and explain what I'm trying to achieve better.

I build a cartesian product (a table that could be up to say 20 columns max but rows could be much more up to a thousand or more - usually no numbers just text) and finalize it and place it on sheet 1 of a workbook and by way of a macro or VBA code I would like to copy and paste it as seen in sheet 2 of the same workbook: 'A' row on sheet 1 go into cell 'A1' of sheet 2, 'B' row of sheet 1 go into 'B1' of sheet 2 and so on until the end of the table ('Nth' row into 'N1') in the format seen in fig 2 (red to red just to show e.g. first 5 columns horizontally with hyphens in between and columns 6 to 13 under Data: with hyphens before them vertically).

Sorry for the confusion! Thanks again.

[Fig 1 Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvwrN.jpg)

[Fig 2 Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dIEe.jpg)

Comment: Post your recorded code and we will fix it up for you.

Comment: when dealing with code with relative referencing on, need to ensure the range in reference. means your Selection Range or Range("this").R1C1. Check your code for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to tackle this, but a loop and some background knowledge of object-oriented programming would do. Perhaps try some version of this in a module:

Sub main()

```
Dim rowEnd As Long
rowEnd = Range("AA" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Rows
For Each cl In Range("A1:A" & rowEnd)
    Range("A" & cl.Row).FormulaR1C1 = Range("AA" & cl.Row).Value
Next

End Sub
```

The sub finds the last row in column AA, then iteratively copies the value from AA to A for each row.

Comment: Changed to Rows.count for you to make it more dynamic and integer to long as integer is converted in run mode to a long but still has integer restrictions (ie max rows you can use will be 32767)

Comment: Excellent, and a great improvement as Excel 2003 does not reach to 1M+ rows. Cheers.